# Wifi can't connect to Internet

Tags: networking, 16.04

I was already having problems previously with my wifi adapter and I found [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2261392)
And since he/she had the exact same problem, adapter, and drivers as me - I followed the steps there.

What happened after I did that is I can connect to a WiFi network, but I cannot connect to the Internet. Whenever I try to go on a website it tells me there is no Internet connection, although in the top right it says I'm connected to my WiFi network. What are the possible causes for this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check your default route with

```
ip route
```

It should say "default" followed by the gateway address of your wireless network.

If you have more than one network connection, for example a wired network and a wireless one, it is possible that you have to tell ubuntu which connection to use to get to the internet.

Comment: It does say "default" and the gateway address. And I only have one network connection set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your WIFI, but no access to the Internet, please check if your WIFI router is connected to the Internet.

The simplest way to test it, is to connect another device/computer to the WIFI and see if you have Internet access using only this WIFI-Router.